# Pagination and filtering from REST API

Tags: rest, pagination

I have a REST API and a web site that uses it. I control both the API and the site.

As an example, I have a /users endpoint that sends back a list of users. Pagination is handled by the API, so in the query string to the API I send

`/users?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10`

The API sends back the first ten records, along with a response header called Pagination which contains e.g. totalRecords = 28 and filteredRecords = 28

So at the client end, I display

"Showing records 1 to 10 of 28 total"

There's also the option to filter by role, so if the user only want users who have the Admin role, they select Admin from a filter dropdown, and the API call becomes

`/users?pageNumber=1&pageSize=10&role=A`

In this case, the Pagination response header might contain totalRecords = 28, filteredRecords = 15

So on the client, it would say

"Showing records 1 to 10 of 15 (filtered from 28 total)"

That's all working exactly as I want it.

But I also have a separate page where I need to show a list of Administrator users, without any filter options at the client side. I add role=A to the query string behind the scenes. That works, but the display still says

"Showing records 1 to 10 of 15 (filtered from 28 total)"

It's working exactly as it should according to the current code, but I feel like on this separate page, it should just say "Showing records 1 to 10 of 15 total" because as far as the user is concerned, they haven't applied a filter.

Is there a standard way to handle this? The two options I've come up with are (a) a separate endpoint for a "pre-filtered" list of users, or (b) a separate parameter to tell the API to treat it as a pre-filtered query, i.e. return totalRecords to be the same as filteredRecords.

Comment: Show us your code where you generate the counts display. You should re-use the exact same filters for the count-of-all as well as the paged results.

Comment: I'm using DataTables (https://www.datatables.net) at the front end so the actual code that generates the counts display is in there, but it does have an option to customise the message, so I was able to tweak it to leave out the bit about "filtered from X total" and that has achieved what I wanted.